# CS50 Week 1 "Half" practice problem is producing unexpected results. What is going wrong here?

Tags: c, function, cs50, decimal-point

I am currently working on the "Half" [practice problem](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/problems/1/half/) in CS50. I am struggling to get the program to output the correct decimal values. First of all, this is my current solution at the moment:

```
// Calculate your half of a restaurant bill
// Data types, operations, type casting, return value

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent));
}

// TODO: Complete the function
float half(float bill, float tax, int tip)
{
    float tax_amt = bill * (tax / 100.0);
    float tip_amt = bill * ((float)tip / 100.0);
    float total = bill + tax_amt + tip_amt;
    return total / 2;
}
```

This is the expected output:

```
Bill before tax and tip: 12.50
Sale Tax Percent: 8.875
Tip percent: 20
**You will owe $8.17 each!**
```

However, my program outputs this instead:

```
Bill before tax and tip: 12.50
Sale Tax Percent: 8.875
Tip percent: 20
**You will owe $8.05 each!**
```

What appears to be my problem here? Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think it's a matter of whether the tip percentage applies to the pre-tax or post-tax amount. You need to check how the problem specifies it.

Comment: Unrelated, but does the CS50 course really tell you do use `float`? Unless you're on a severely constrained system there's really no need to use `float`, and haven't been for many years (decades even). Use `double` for all your floating point values. In fact, your calculations are all done using `double` values, and the values in your `float` variables will be *promoted* to `double`.

Comment: Thanks! Changing this line to "float tip_amt = (bill + tax_amt) * ((float)tip / 100.0)" fixed the problem :). The tip was applied after tax, which I had missed.

Comment: @brinkbrink Please write up a quick answer.